# PrimeFaces datatable (V 3.3.1) sorting not working properly

Tags: sorting, jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

I'm having issue with primefaces datatable sorting when I have `<p:cellEditor>` column, other columns are sorted correctly.

```
 <p:column headerText="#{message.label_code}"  sortBy="#{item.code}">
            <p:cellEditor>
    <f:facet name="output">
          <h:outputText value="#{item.code}" />
    </f:facet>
   <f:facet name="input">
         <p:inputText value="#{item.code}" style="width:100%"/>
   </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor> </p:column>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is defect of primefaces 3.3.1. It was reported as an issue http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4173 and it should be resolved in version 3.4.
Try update primefaces to higher version.

Comment: Thanks @tomi, yeah i was a bug in version 3.3.1 and it works fine with version 3.4